# WSO2 SP: Construct JSON object from stream

Tags: wso2, siddhi, wso2-streaming-integrator

I'm trying to generate a JSON object, from a stream of JSON data, using below clode:

```
@sink(type='log')
define stream TempStream(designation object);

from TestStream
select json:setElement("{}", "$", json:getString(json,"$.DESIGNATION"), "designation") as designation
insert into TempStream;
```

But the output data having null value. Is there any issue with the code, please?

```
TempStream : Event{timestamp=1554192487415, data=[null], isExpired=false}
```

The input stream having data passed as below:

```
TestStream : Event{timestamp=1554192487415, data=[{"STATUS":"AA","CREATED_DATE":"2010-11-23 10:24:36","DESIGNATION":"Manager"}], isExpired=false}
```

Comment: Can anybody throw some light to this, please?

Answer (score 1):

I have checked this on a SP 4.3.0 pack and I was able to get the following result

```
 SiddhiApp : TempStream : Event{timestamp=1554733451717, data=[{designation=Manager}], isExpired=false}
```

The Query that I used as follows with the event that I send to the "**TestStream**",

```
@sink(type='log',"TEMPSTREAM")
define stream TempStream(designation object);

@sink(type='log')
define stream TestStream(json string);

from TestStream
select json:setElement("{}", "$", json:getString(json,"$.DESIGNATION"), "designation") as designation
insert into TempStream;
```

```
SiddhiApp : TestStream : Event{timestamp=1554733451717, data=[{ "STATUS": "AA", "CREATED_DATE": "2010-11-23 10:24:36", "DESIGNATION": "Manager" } ], isExpired=false}
```

I beleave this is the result that you are expecting.

Comment: Thanks @anusha-jayasundara. The code is exactly the same, I'm on SO 4.3.0 as well. Not sure whats missing on my side. Also the data is not a proper JSON format, it is in key=value format, instead of key:value format. `data=[{designation=Manager}]`

Comment: I'm having siddhi-execution-json-1.1.0.jar and siddhi-map-json-4.1.0.jar and other default jars comes with SP 4.3.0, just in case if the versions matter.